# Website is not loading inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using firefox as my browser. I am using this code to simply test to load a diffrent website inside the iframe. But the website is still not loading

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <body>

        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>

     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no issue with your code. It is working fine on mine. Make sure you have a latest version of firefox. Please let me know if there is any issue.

```html
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" height="250px">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: yeah, now its loading, some ssl issues are there